# deactivate and activate scroll on body on mobile browser

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

I have this code, which works goods:

```
$(".menu").on("click",function(event) {      
    $(".navigation").css("opacity", "1");    
    $('body').on('touchmove', function (e) {
         if (!$('.info').has($(e.target)).length) e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

So what I want to do is to get the scroll back once I hide the div opacity. I'm trying to work with this piece of code, but i can't get it.

```
$(".menu-i-cerrar").on('click', function() {   
    $(".navigation").css("opacity", "0");
    $('body').on('touchmove', function (e) {
         return true;
    });                                                                                                                          
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the logic in a function and then toggle it off and on.

```
var disableScrollDueToSomething = function (e) {
     if (!$('.info').has($(e.target)).length) e.preventDefault();
};

$('body').on('touchmove', disableScrollDueToSomething);

//later to remove it
$('body').off('touchmove', disableScrollDueToSomething);
```